# IE workaround for converting an XML document into a string?

Tags: javascript, xml, jquery

Right now, I have the following:

```
function jQueryToString( jQueryObject )
{
   return $('<div>').append(jQueryObject.clone()).remove().html();
}
```

Which works swimmingly in firefox, opera, chrome, and safari. However, it breaks in IE. I need to convert an XML Document object into a string, so what are my options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For IE, do this:

```
jQueryObject.each( function( e, elem ){
$('#someDiv').append( elem.xml );
} );
```

Answer (score -1):

Disclaimer: I haven't tried this but how about

```
function jQueryToString( jQueryObject )
{
   var arr = $.map(jQueryObject, function(v) {
                 return $(this).html();
             });
   return arr.join('');
}
```